# What happens when a thread calls System.exit()?

Tags: java, multithreading

What exactly occurs? Does the thread stop, or does the program stop? How can I stop the main thread then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean the [`System.exit`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) (or [`Runtime.exit`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit%28int%29)) call, which has the effect of terminating the entire JVM, regardless of which thread calls it.

Individual threads are only stopped when their "run" method terminates, and in the case of the main thread, this is a main method; however, when this thread stops then so does the JVM, unless there is any non-[daemon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29) thread running.  So to "stop" the main thread without terminating the JVM you can create and start another thread before the main method terminates.

```
public class SleepThread extends Thread {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Thread t = new SleepThread();
    t.start();
    System.err.println("Main thread exiting.");
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.err.println("Thread running.");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(5 * 1000); // 5 seconds
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
      System.err.println("INTERRUPTED");
    }
    System.err.println("Thread exiting.");
  }
}
```

Comment: More exactly: when the last non-daemon thread stops, the VM exits, whether or not this is the main thread. (You could even make the main thread a daemon thread, but I would not recommend it.)

Answer (score 3):

The thread stops when you `return` from its `run()` method.

The main thread is just another thread (albeit slightly special), you either return from `main()` or you call `System.exit()` to stop the JVM.

**Edit**: The above is a little muddy, as noted in the comment below.

Note that stopping the main thread by returning from it doesn't automatically stop your other threads, and the JVM will continue to run them until they stop or you kill the JVM process.

Comment: Your last sentence is contradicting itself - returning from `main()` does not automatically stop the JVM.

Comment: No, it stops the main thread. But you're right - the way I wrote it isn't as clear as it should be, I'll edit - thanks.